# Repaint method compiling improperly

Tags: java, swing, timer, repaint, timertask

I am trying to use repaint in a timer task, but eclipse is telling me the method is undefined, and I don't know why.  I believe I have all the proper imports.  Below is just a small segment of my code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Timer;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

class task extends TimerTask
{
    public void run()
    {
        repaint();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your `task` class doesn't seem to extend JPanel (so you won't be able to call JPanel methods)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a method that has not been declared in the class it is held in, and so Java, not "Eclipse" is complaining, and rightfully so.

If you are trying to redraw a Swing GUI component intermittently using a timer then,

- Use a Swing Timer, not a java.util.Timer, since the latter does not handle Swing threading properly.
- Call `repaint()` on a Swing component, not on nothing as you're doing.
- Most important, go through the Java and Java Swing tutorials, as it will explain all of this and more.

For example, try running this straight, and then try running it stoned. It's almost psychedelic:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyRepaint extends JPanel {

   private static final Color COLOR_1 = Color.RED;
   private static final Color COLOR_2 = Color.BLUE;
   private static final int PREF_W = 400;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final int DELAY = 25;
   private int x1 = 0;
   private int y1 = 0;

   private int x2 = 20;
   private int y2 = 20;
   Paint myPaint = new GradientPaint(x1, y1, COLOR_1, x2, y2, COLOR_2, true);

   public MyRepaint() {
      new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            x1++;
            y1++;
            x2++;
            y2++;

            x1 %= PREF_W;
            y1 %= PREF_H;
            x2 %= PREF_W;
            y2 %= PREF_H;
            myPaint = new GradientPaint(x1, y1, COLOR_1, x2, y2, COLOR_2, true);

            // the repaint method call below works because it is calling it on
            // the current object of this class, which extends JPanel
            // and thus has a repaint() method.
            repaint();
         }
      }).start();
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setPaint(myPaint);
      g2.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      MyRepaint mainPanel = new MyRepaint();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyRepaint");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```